# ImageCache is reset to zero when I open iOS plugin by MethodChannel

Tags: swift, flutter, image, caching

I am trying to use iOS image picker plugin in my Flutter using MethodChannel.

But I found that if I open and close the image picker(My Image Picker button), ImageCache is reset to zero.

So NetworkImage gets loading again like it has never been downloaded before.

On the other hand, Flutter's image picker(Flutter Image Picker button) doesn't reset ImageCache to zero so it is fine.

Why is this happening? Did I miss something?
I have tried overriding ImageCache size like below but the problem is not solved:

[overriding image cache in Flutter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bjd2y.png)

Please help me...

[my app home tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02V2n.png)

[my app image tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXpTP.png)

[flutter image picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDtac.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use flutter package to make developer easier to code and even the package also use MethodChannel, inside code is also coded pretty well such as error handler etc. It is also works for IOS and Android, which is this is the function of Flutter that make developer easier to deploy IOS and Android apps.

You can explore more about this:
https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker
https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image/example

Comment: Thank you but I don’t want flutter’s image picker because I want picker UI customization like instagram.. and CachedNetworkImage also doesn’t solve my problem…